# Fans are always running

Tags: 13.10, dell, power-management, fan, inspiron

Whenever I turn my laptop on my fans are running as if I was playing a game. The air coming out is cool, none of my computer parts are warm. I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I have a Dell Inspiron 3521.
Thanks to anyone who is willing to help me.

Comment: Check if this link helps you: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/controlling-dell-fan-speeds-temperature-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/

Comment: On another page, check if the bios is at least at version A07 --- A06 had a bug with the fans. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19494484.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Dell Precision / M90.
They use small air ducts to direct the cooling air from the fans to the components.
After disassembling my unit I found that these air ducts were clogged.

Fixed my problem...
   Good luck.

Comment: I had Windows8 yesterday and my fans were running fine. I installed Ubuntu because a file was corrupt and it wouldn't let me reset my computer without a Windows8 CD, which I don't have. But whatever the problem is has to do with the OS I believe.

Answer (score 0):

does your pc have nvidia or amd graphics card?

my friend has a dell inspiron with nvidia graphics card. on a fresh install, it overheats and the battery backup was half what windows gave. i installed bumblebee and it works perfectly fine now. you should install bumblebee only if you have a second graphics card(nvidia graphics card along with integrated intel hd graphics)

you can also open system monitor and look for processes if they have a lot of cpu usage on idle, usually not more than 10% of cpu is used. if there is a lot of cpu usage, then report it.

Comment: How would I check? Sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: you bought the laptop. don't you remember the configuration of it. by the way, if you have a graphics card, there would be a sticker on the laptop of nvidia or amd graphics along with the core processor sticker. if you have windows try right click on desktop select Properties >> Settings >> Advanced >> Adapter and you will see what type of graphics card the computer has.

Comment: Well I don't have a graphics card sticker. So I guess all I have is the integrated one.

Comment: When I'm not doing anything my CPU usage is about 9%. Like I said earlier, the air coming out is cool and all of my parts are at normal temperatures.

Comment: relax. there must be no problem. if you have windows, check the speed of fan in windows. it must be the same. the fan is usually controlled by bios and is OS independent

Comment: I don't have Windows. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and did not dual boot it alongside Windows 8.